Why do we lose information of the multiplied matrices after matrix multiplication?
"given that a, b are matrices and the product is defined, product ab has been evaluated, the elements a and b can not be recovered from it." I understand that there isn't a division of matrices which would give back a one of the matrices but I don't understand the full scope of this statement, as to why we lose this information.

If $a$ and $b$ are single numbers, we can't recover either of them from their product $ab$. Why should it be different for matrices?

If $a,b$ are square matrices, then $ab=(ac)(c^{-1}b)$ for any invertible matrix $c$.

That's true for all kinds of products.
For example, if $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, then you cannot recover $a$ and $b$ from their product $p=ab$. For example, if $ab=1$, then you cannot say anything about $a$ and $b$ except $b=\frac{1}{a}$.
Sometimes, you can get some information like a short list of possible values. For example, nonzero integers only have a finite number of factors. For instance, if $a$ and $b$ are integers and $ab=6$, then you know that $a\in\{1,2,3,6,-1,-2,-3,-6\}$ (same for $b$)
For matrices, it is the same. There are many matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AB=I$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix). It is even worse for matrices in some sense: even knowing that $A=B$, you cannot recover $A$ from $A^2$ since for example, there are infinitely many square matrices $A$ such $A^2=I$ (while for real numbers, when $p\ge 0$, $a^2=p \iff a=\sqrt{p}\text{ or }a=-\sqrt{p}$, which is not so bad).

Perspective changing. Thank you!
